# Get only the lines that appear only once and delete all lines that have 2 or more occurrences in Vim

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a text file with:

```
Bar
Foo
Bar
Foo
Baz
Bar
```

And **I want only the unique lines that doesn't have more than 1 occurence**:

```
Baz
```

I use `:sort ui` but it returns:

```
Bar
Baz
Foo
```

How can I get the lines that doesn't have any repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first sort the lines, then replace any line followed by that line duplicated any number of times with an empty string:

e.g.

```
:sort i
:%s/^\(.\{-1,\}$\)\n\?\(\1$\n\?\)\+//gi
```

Comment: Lets tighten up that substitution some: `%s/\(.*\)\n\(\1$\n\)\+//` or if you use the very magic flag: `%s/\v(.*)\n(\1$\n)+//`. Note: this may leave an empty line at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Time for some awk:

```
:%!awk '{a[$0]++} END{ for(k in a){ if(a[k] == 1) { print k }} }'
```

The idea is simple: Read each line into a hash table as the key and increment the value. This means the value will store the number of times a line has been seen. After you are done reading the file then loop through the hash table and print out each key that is seen only once.