# Vi: delete only not-first (second, third, …) occurence of multiple lines

Tags: vim, vi

How to delete every occurence of multiple lines in a text file except the first one? ([This question might be related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459942))
I need to keep the order, otherwise I had used `:sort u`.

Example:

```
hsdf
asdf
csdf
csdf
hsdf
dsdf
jsdf
asdf
```

results in

```
hsdf
asdf
csdf
dsdf
jsdf
```

instead of

```
asdf
csdf
dsdf
hsdf
jsdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't need to think much. Just take that big hammer and make a bang.

So what's the plan? Loop over all lines; store them into associative array; if it's already there then delete it from buffer. Looks dumb enough to get things working by the first attempt:

```
:let foo = {}
:g/./if foo->has_key(getline(".")) | delete | else | let foo[getline(".")] = 1 | endif
:unlet foo
```